# Does XAMPP set the php.ini file to "date.timezone=Europe/Berline" during installation?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, xampp

Does XAMPP set the php.ini file to "`date.timezone=Europe/Berline`" during installation?

The default `date.timezone` settings are stored in the `../xampp/php/php.ini` file.
These settings can be found around in or around line 1045. After reviewing some php error logs and the php.ini file, I found that my settings were as follows:

```
date.timezone=Europe/Berline
```

I am located in the United States, Eastern Time, so my settings should be:

```
date.timezone=America/New_York
```

I am not sure why my `date.timezone` would be set to `Europe/Berline` unless this is the default setting for the php.ini file during an XAMPP installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is set to default during installation, here a link to show you what to  change it to if you haven't already

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: The default setting is in the php.ini file. You state that this is the default during installation, can you share a link that validates what you are seeing to be true?